# How to handle events from Multiple forms of the same class

Tags: vb.net, events

I create a number of sub-forms, each of the same class, from my parent form.
Each of the subforms defines an event that should cause the parent form to create a new subform of a different class. - However only the latest created sub form is having it's events handled.

Thinking that it is because I have reused the reference to the sub-form, I store each of the subforms in a linked list of type subform.

SubForm Code.

```
Public Class UserEditor
Property ID As Integer
Public Event EditGroup(ByRef group As GroupPrincipal, ByVal newWindow As Boolean, ByVal Source As Integer)

Public Sub New(ByVal U As UserPrincipal, ByVal theId As Integer)
    InitializeComponent()
    ID = theId
    UserEditor1.DisplayUserPrincipal(U)
End Sub

Private Sub UserEditor1_GroupEdit(ByRef groupItem As GroupListItem) Handles UserEditor1.GroupEdit
    RaiseEvent EditGroup(groupItem.Grp, False, ID)
End Sub
```

Code on parentform

```
Public Class ASADManager
Dim WithEvents UserEditorInstance As UserEditor
Dim WithEvents UserEditorList As New List(Of UserEditor)
```

This code triggered on selection of leafobject in a displayed list.

```
If TypeOf leafObject Is UserPrincipal Then
                    UserEditorInstance = New UserEditor(currentLeaf.Principal, UserEditorList.Count) With {
                        .Text = currentLeaf.SamAccountName
                    }
                    UserEditorInstance.Show()
                    UserEditorInstance.Activate()
                    UserEditorList.Add(UserEditorInstance)
End If


Private Sub EditGroup(ByRef grp As GroupPrincipal, newWindow As Boolean, Source As Integer) Handles UserEditorInstance.EditGroup
    If Not newWindow Then
        Dim GEdit As New GroupEditorForm(grp) With {
            .Text = grp.Name
        }
        GEdit.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Everything works fine in the latest opened UserEditorInstance, it captures and re-throws the event, and that is cause by the parent, which opens the GroupEditor form.

However, if I select a 2nd LeafObject (to open another UserEditor window) it's events are trapped, and not the previous.

How do I trap both?

Hope this explanation makes it clear what I am doing (and doing wrong)

Comment: Ps. I know that the If Not newWindow is doing the opposite of what I want :-)  I just want the events handling correctly at the moment, then I will figure out the re-use of forms

Comment: You set the `UserEditorInstance` to the each instance you create, thus it always holds the instance of the last class you created. Then, the event handler has:  `Handles UserEditorInstance.EditGroup`. Remove this and use AddHandler/RemoveHandler to add the event handler to each class instance you create (and remove it when a class instance is disposed). You may want to create a specialized class that adds/removes instances and the related handler.

Comment: Yep, that's fixed it.  Thanks.  If you want to put that as a solution I can close this.
Many thanks.